# Using pg library in getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js

I am trying to add a SQL query to populate a Next.js page from a Postgres database. I had it working for a while but I seem to have broken it. I've traced the issue to this exact line:

```
import { Client } from 'pg';
```

This basically imports a Postgres client that I can use to connect to a local Postgres database. When this line is at the top of my index.js, I get the error `"Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs"` when I navigate to the page or try to build (the full stack trace shows that `fs` is being included by `pg`).

When I comment it out, the error goes away.

From searching I think it has something to do w/ the fact that this is server-side code that's getting included in the client code. However import statements have to go at the top of the file, so I'm not sure how I could possibly avoid this.

The *rest* of my Postgres code is within getServerSideProps, but I'm not able to move the import statement there as I mentioned:

```
import { Client } from 'pg';
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const client = new Client({
    host: '...', ...
  })

  await client.connect()
 
  const res = await client.query(
    "SELECT blogpost_content FROM ..."
  )
  await client.end()

  const dbmsg = res.rows[0].blogpost_content;
  return {
    props: {
      dbmsg
    },
  };
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to next.js so it seems like I could have chosen the wrong way to connect to a database. However this was not covered in the tutorial I'm following so I'm sort of winging it. Happy for all suggestions big and small!

Answer (score 1):

I think is because this lib use `'fs'`(file system) that serverless functions don't work with. How Nextjs is builded to run natively with serveless environment you will need a client with connection using an endpoint that serverless function will call to persisty the data. I know some libs to help working with node-pg in serveless environment like [here](https://github.com/MatteoGioioso/serverless-pg), but i like work with `prisma`, `mongoose`, and others orm's that handle this communication and make more easy, just setting an env url.  In some cases if you need this to run in large scale its common use a pool before connect with your database like [pgbouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/), because how serverless functions runs in paralels yours database will handle a lot of connections at same time.

But after all this i say you can simple run the postgres in a docker container and use some client on the nextjs to connect with. Or use postgres client on your computer but locale with your `localhost:5432` to not use direcly the file system of node.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up having to just move to Prisma. I wasn't enthusiastic about that because I didn't really want all the bells-and-whistles that Prisma provides, but it lets me write raw SQL so it's good enough. So far that seems to have solved my problem.